# How to develop toolbar with XUL

Tags: xul, toolbar

I'm a beginner and I've never used XUL, I've downloaded XULRunner , Could anyone tell me how to start with it. all I need is to design a toolbar.

Comment: Since "toolbars" are usually add-ons for existing apps, you probably didn't need XULRunner. Do you want to create a toolbar for Firefox? In this case you need to develop a Firefox extension and XULRunner won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Read "[Getting Started with XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner)"

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small standalone XUL application : see http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2009/02/standalone-xul-application-translating.html
This application contains a toolbar.

hope it helps

[image]